# Overwrite an Element in a Tree with Java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have to overwrite an element in a tree. The class tree has a key, a left and a right. Let's say it isn't a BST.

Here is my code so far. It works for fine for the left half of the tree but not for right half. I think it's just a minor change to make it work but I can't get it done without some help.

```
public T overwriteOne(TreeNode<T> tree, T element, T newElement) {
    if (tree == null)
        return null;

    if (tree.key.equals(element)) {
        tree.key = newElement;
        return tree.key;
    }
    else if (tree.left != null) {
        return overwriteOne(tree.left, element, newElement);
    }
    else if (tree.right != null){
        return overwriteOne (tree.right, element, newElement);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: could you eleborate `but not for right half` a little bit more?

Comment: Please explain exactly how it doesn't work. (It *could* be because you're using a German tree in the last condition.)

Comment: Ok, let me specify the problem:
This method finds elements within the left subtree. Everything that begins with "tree.left. ...". Even "tree.left.left.right" for example.
But it doesn't find elements  in the right subtree beginning with tree.right.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work if the node you are searching for is in the right branch. If the left branch is not null it calls recursively into the left and ignores the right.

In general you would be using a tree to speed the search for an element. Elements that are less than the current node's are stored to the left and elements that are greater than the current node's are stored to the right.

I would expect you code should look something like:

```
public T overwriteOne(TreeNode<T> tree, T element, T newElement) {
    if (tree == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (tree.key.equals(element)) {
        tree.key = newElement;
    } else if (tree.key.compareTo(element) < 0) {
        return overwriteOne(tree.left, element, newElement);
    } else if (tree.key.compareTo(element) > 0) {
        return overwriteOne(tree.right, element, newElement);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You don't need to test if `tree.left` or `tree.right` are null because that's the first test in the recursive call.

If the tree isn't ordered then you'll need to test both left and right branches:

```
T result = overwriteOne(tree.left, element, newElement);
if (result == null)
    result = overwriteOne(tree.right, element, newElement);
return result;
```

Comment: Hi Sprinter, thank you for your fast reply. Your code works. But what if the tree isn't a search tree so the elements aren't ordererd?

Comment: I'll add a section to the answer for that

Answer (score 0):

To start with:

- *Don't return* immediately after traversing only the left subtree; by doing that you are not traversing the right subtree at all, which is incorrect!
- Before returning, you are not checking if the element is found or not. It is very much possible that you may return with NULL, while the element may still be present in the tree.
- `else-if` doesn't apply here. If left-subtree is there, doesn't mean right-subtree can be simply skipped.

Each nodes of the tree must be traversed in order to confirm whether an element is present(can be replaced) or not.

Given below is the code to make it work:

```
public T overwriteOne(TreeNode<T> tree, T element, T newElement) {
    if (tree == null) return null;

    T returnVal = null;

    if (tree.key.equals(element)) {
        tree.key = newElement;
        returnVal = tree.key;
    }
    if (tree.left != null) {
        returnVal = overwriteOne(tree.left, element, newElement);
    }
    if (returnVal == null && tree.right != null){
        returnVal = overwriteOne (tree.right, element, newElement);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```